# CSS Absolute positioning 100% height less padding without JS

Tags: css, height, absolute

The following code has a DIV that needs to be positioned at the top of the container, another at the bottom and then the content needs to come through in the middle.

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; width:100%; height:40px"></div>

<div class="howto"></div>

<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; height:40px"></div>
```

So we don't know the height of the containing DIV. How without JS can the div with class `howto` have the height of the container DIV less the height of the absolute positioned div at the top and bottom so as to contain content between these 2 DIVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you wish to accomplish, this is one possible solution:

@tinkerbin: http://tinkerbin.com/QsaCPgR6

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>

    <div class="howto">
      Has height set to auto. You may change that if you want to.
    </div>

    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px 0; /* top and bottom padding = .header and .footer padding*/
}

.header,
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  top: 0;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

.howto {
  height: /*specifiy one if you wish to*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a pure CSS way to do what you're trying to do without JS.

See this previous post on SA:

[Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space)